# How to return 0 value if no record exists in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I need find out  for  which date record does not exits in BigQuery table.

Query pls find

```
select cast(creat_ts as date) as create,IFNULL(count(*) ,0) 
FROM table  
where cast(creat_ts as date)='2020-06-23' group by 1 )
```

Comment: Is not worked and i have tried collapse,with as clause but no luck

Answer (score 2):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT DISTINCT day
FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2020-06-01', '2020-06-30')) day
LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.table` t
ON CAST(creat_ts AS DATE) = day
WHERE creat_ts IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks its working i have try to array data but not able thought subset part

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
with calendar as (
  select * from unnest(generate_date_array('2020-01-01', '2020-07-01', interval 1 day)) date
),
temp as (
  select cast(b.create_ts as date) as date from `project.dataset.table` b
),
daily_count as (
  select
    date,
    count(date.temp) as ct
  from calendar
  left join temp using(date)
  group by 1
)
select * from daily_count
where ct = 0
order by 1
```